# pandas, set value for column y,z on condition of column x with outsource data

Tags: python, pandas

there is a data with columns=[x,t,y,z], and I want to fill column [y,z] with outsource data.

The following codes works fine for fill column y.

```
    # data I want to fill
df=pd.DataFrame([['x1','t','NaN','Nan'],['x2','t','NaN','Nan'],
                 ['x2','t','NaN','Nan'],['x3','t','NaN','Nan'],
                 ['x3','t','NaN','Nan'],['x4','t','NaN','Nan'],
                 ['x5','t','NaN','Nan']],
                 columns=list(['x','t','y','z']))

# source data
source=pd.DataFrame([['x1','y1','z1'],['x2','y2','z2'],['x3','y3','z3'],
                     ['x4','y4','z4']],columns=list(['x','y','z']))


print('df before\n',df)

def applyFunc(x):
    for i in range(0,len(source)):
        if x==source.at[i,'x']: 
            return source.at[i,'y']
    else:
        return 1

df['y']=df['x'].apply(applyFunc)

print('\n\ndf after:\n',df)
```

the result it runs is as following:

```
df before
     x  t    y    z
0  x1  t  NaN  Nan
1  x2  t  NaN  Nan
2  x2  t  NaN  Nan
3  x3  t  NaN  Nan
4  x3  t  NaN  Nan
5  x4  t  NaN  Nan
6  x5  t  NaN  Nan


df after:
     x  t   y    z
0  x1  t  y1  Nan
1  x2  t  y2  Nan
2  x2  t  y2  Nan
3  x3  t  y3  Nan
4  x3  t  y3  Nan
5  x4  t  y4  Nan
6  x5  t   1  Nan
```

what I want is filling columns [y,z] at one time.
the result I want to get like this.

```
df after:
         x  t   y    z
    0  x1  t  y1  z1
    1  x2  t  y2  z2
    2  x2  t  y2  z2
    3  x3  t  y3  z3
    4  x3  t  y3  z3
    5  x4  t  y4  z4
    6  x5  t   1  1
```

I have tried, but I haven't find a way to get it.I tried the following code

```
def applyFunc(x):
    for i in range(0,len(source)):
        if x==source.at[i,'x']: 
            return (source.at[i,'y'],source.at[i,'z'])
    else:
        return (1,1)

df['y','z']=df['x'].apply(applyFunc)
```

while the result is like this.

```
df after:
     x  t    y    z    (y, z)
0  x1  t  NaN  Nan  (y1, z1)
1  x2  t  NaN  Nan  (y2, z2)
2  x2  t  NaN  Nan  (y2, z2)
3  x3  t  NaN  Nan  (y3, z3)
4  x3  t  NaN  Nan  (y3, z3)
5  x4  t  NaN  Nan  (y4, z4)
6  x5  t  NaN  Nan    (1, 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your function like this:

```
def applyFunc(x, col):
    for i in range(0, len(source)):
        if x == source.at[i, 'x']: 
            return source.at[i, col]
    else:
        return 1
```

And then simply:

```
df['y'] = df['x'].apply(applyFunc, col='y')
df['z'] = df['x'].apply(applyFunc, col='z')
```

Of course you can loop across 'y' and 'z' like so:

```
for col in ['y', 'z']:
    df[col] = df['x'].apply(applyFunc, col=col)
```

Or, if you really want it in one line:

```
df['y'], df['z'] = df['x'].apply(applyFunc, col='y'), df['x'].apply(applyFunc, col='z')
```

Comment: Note that you don't need the `else:` in applyFunc either. so simply `return 1` indented at the same level as the `for` also works, and is cleaner.